# ksqlDB Producer has been fenced by another producer with the same transactionalId

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm trying out ksqlDB but I keep getting this error:

```
Producer with transactionalId 'default_' and ProducerIdAndEpoch(producerId=16, epoch=94)
has been fenced by another producer with the same transactionalId
```

I'm running ksql queries using the REST api, e.g. sending a POST request to http://localhost:8088/ksql with the body:

```
{ ksql: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "foo"' }
```

The api response contains the above error. I'm running queries using the api many times in scripts, sometimes concurrently, but I'd assume ksqlDB can handle concurrent requests.

There are related questions on SO, but the answers are either timeout issues or bugs in the producer. I'm getting this error within a few seconds of calling the api, so it shouldn't be timing out. Also, I'm not writing any custom producer code, I'm just running ksqlDB queries and I'd assume ksqlDB is fairly robust.

How can I fix this error?